# Cloudfront for naked domain name wordpress problem

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, cname

I have created a WordPress website (mywebsite.com) and wanted to use cloudfront.
In the wizard, it asked me to add the below CNAME record in my DNS records.

```
Name               Type     Value
mywebsite.com      CNAME    xxx123.cloudfront.net
```

But when I tried to enter that in my DNS records I got an error that it is not allowed. What is your solution for this?

Note: I even tested this with Route 53 and got a similar error:

(InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name mywebsite.com. is not permitted at apex in zone mywebsite.com.)

Comment: Use alias record for apex domain

Comment: @jellycsc do you mean I have to create A records to IP4 and IP6? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of having dynamic IP addresses to the various regions?

Comment: No, alias record is different from A record. See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-create-alias-records/) for more details.